# Access table form field's data from submitForm

Tags: 8, forms

I'm building a custom form and it display well. My form has a table type field which I can't manage to access from the submitForm method.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $form['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
        '#required' => true,
    ];

    $form['template_components_list'] = [
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#caption' => $this
        ->t('My table.'),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
        '#header' => array(
            $this
            ->t('row_name'),
            $this
            ->t('description'),
            $this
            ->t('actions'),
        ),
    ];

    $form['template_components_list'][0]['row_name'] = array(
        '#plain_text' => 'Test1',
    );

    $form['template_components_list'][1]['row_name'] = array(
        '#plain_text' => 'Test2',
    );

    $form['actions'] = [
                '#type' => 'actions',
            ];
    // Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
            ];

    return $form;
}
```

I'm then trying to access the values in submitForm from multiple ways (some creating errors but I want to show I tried them)

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r('START', TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($form_state->getValue('row_name'), TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($form_state->get('row_name'), TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($form_state->get('row_name')->getValue(), TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($form_state->getValue('template_components_list'), TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($form_state->get('template_components_list'), TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($form_state->get('template_components_list')->getValue(), TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r('END', TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
}
```

}

I got only empty messages or errors in my logs

> Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null

What is the good way to access my table rows values from submitForm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I must have overlooked the way you built the form. Unless you make your values in the table row part of the form, you cannot submit them. I changed the row '#type' to a text field and added a default value, in that way you can now pass that along with your form. 
Try this:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $form['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
        '#required' => true,
    ];

    $form['template_components_list'] = [
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#caption' => $this
        ->t('My table.'),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
        '#header' => array(
            $this
            ->t('row_name'),
            $this
            ->t('description'),
            $this
            ->t('actions'),
        ),
    ];

    $form['template_components_list'][0]['row_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
         '#default_value' => 'Test1'

    );

    $form['template_components_list'][1]['row_name'] = array(
              '#type' => 'textfield',
         '#default_value' => 'Test2'

    );

    $form['actions'] = [
                '#type' => 'actions',
            ];
    // Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
            ];

    return $form;
}



public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{

   $SubmittedValues = $form_state->getValues();
   print_r($SubmittedValues);
   //Now you can access the form values as an associative array 
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r('START', TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($SubmittedValues['row_name'], TRUE) . '</code></pre>');

    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r($SubmittedValues['template_components_list'], TRUE) . '</code></pre>');

    \Drupal::logger('some_channel_name')->warning('<pre><code>' . print_r('END', TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't seems to work, I've made a "kint($SubmittedValues)" I see my table but it's empty

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: It does work thank you ! :)